# How to disable the Registration using abp.io

Tags: abp

I’m trying to disable the registration unfortunately i cannot find the class allowing me to be able to disable the registration, and when i go to the source code of the module manage the registration,(https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/account/src) the Domain.shared is not exist.

how to do this ?

Thank you in advance.

info: i'm using abp.io 3.3.1 community edition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `"Abp.Account.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled"` to `false` under `"Settings"` in `appsettings.json`, as shown below:

[image: screenshot example]